# UITextField doesn't respond on iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uitextfield, uiwindow

I have an `abstract class` that is a `UIView` subclass.

It creates a view on a new `UIWindow` and shows my `Custom alert` to users.

I have an `AuthorizationView` class inherited from this abstract class and it contains some `UITextFields`.

**The problem is**: these `UITextFields` doesn't respond on `iOS 7.1 beta` if I build it now and send to testers.
Old versions of project work fine (from AppStore) on iOS 7.1 beta.
Any version works fine on iOS 6.0 - iOS 7.0. I have no possibility to test it myself on iOS 7.1 beta.

Any suggestions?

`UITextField` creation:

```
fieldUser = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:AUTH_FIELD_USER_FRAME];
[fieldUser setBackgroundColor:kColorClear];
[fieldUser setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
[fieldUser setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
[fieldUser setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
[fieldUser setKeyboardAppearance:[[DatabaseManager sharedInstance] keyboard]];
[fieldUser setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
[fieldUser setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
[fieldUser setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
[fieldUser setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyNext];
[fieldUser setDelegate:self];
[fieldUser setPlaceholder:NSLocalizedString(@"Window_Login_Placeholder_User", @"")];
[fieldUser setFont:kFontNormal(16.0f)];
[self addSubview:fieldUser];
```

Abstract class:

```
#import "AlertWindow.h"

@interface AlertWindow ()
{
    CGFloat alpha;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;

@end

@implementation AlertWindow

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        alpha = 0.8f;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        alpha = 0.8f;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) showAnimated:(BOOL)animated_
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [view setAlpha:alpha];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
    self.window.backgroundColor = kColorClear;
    [self.window addSubview:view];
    [self.window addSubview:self];
    self.window.alpha = 0.0f;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    if (animated_)
    {
        __block UIWindow *animationWindow = self.window;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration animations:^{
            animationWindow.alpha = 1.0f;
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        self.window.alpha = 1.0f;
    }
}

- (void) hideAnimated:(BOOL)animated_
{
    if (animated_)
    {
        __block UIWindow *animationWindow = self.window;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration animations:^{
            animationWindow.alpha = 0.0f;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            self.window.hidden = YES;
            self.window = nil;
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        self.window.hidden = YES;
        self.window = nil;
    }
}

- (void) hideAnimated
{
    [self hideAnimated:YES];
}

- (void) setBackgroundAplha:(CGFloat)alpha_
{
    alpha = alpha_;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

All the Event Delegate methods will touch the main Window of the application. Now you have created another window, may be your delegate is calling, but hiding because this new Window. Just make window color clear color and verify, or else try with printing text of Text Field entering some text, will let you know is triggered or not?

Comment: I don't think that the problem is inside the delegate. Text field acts like an image. It doesn't respond to a touch inside the text area.

Comment: @iWheelBuy my intention is to say, Delegate method invoking when we click on text field.